# alphabetical tie-breakers in lists python

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list that looks like this:

```
['Ivan Connolly,50', 'Claudia Zingaro,50', 'Jeffie Honaker,50', 'Floria Rozar,49', 'Hyun Castleberry,48', 'Invalid Name,48', 'Cristi Authement,47', 'Yadira Millwood,47', 'Invalid Name,46']
```

The numbers represent student test scores. I want to use the sorted() function to sort the list out in student ranking, and tie breakers are names in alphabetical order. I am not too familiar with this function, so your help would be greatly appreciated! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `key` parameter with `sorted()`, and adding your own function.

```
>>> L = ['Ivan Connolly,50', 'Claudia Zingaro,50', 'Jeffie Honaker,50', 'Floria Rozar,49', 'Hyun Castleberry,48', 'Invalid Name,48', 'Cristi Authement,47', 'Yadira Millwood,47', 'Invalid Name,46']
>>> def mysort(x):
...     temp = x.split(',')
...     return (-int(temp[1]), temp[0])
... 
>>> sorted(L, key=mysort)
['Claudia Zingaro,50', 'Ivan Connolly,50', 'Jeffie Honaker,50', 'Floria Rozar,49', 'Hyun Castleberry,48', 'Invalid Name,48', 'Cristi Authement,47', 'Yadira Millwood,47', 'Invalid Name,46']
```

---

The function is called with each value in the list. The function will return something like `[46, 'Invalid Name']`. Then, `sorted()` sees this and sorts it based on the list given, the first item having more priority.

Comment: +1 but you should use `int(temp[1])` to deal correctly with 1-digit scores.

Comment: @flornquake True, fixing

Comment: I'd probably go so far as to use `temp[0].rsplit(None, 1)[::-1]` for a bit more of a standard name sorting

Comment: @Haidro, that is almost what i need, but it needs to have the higher scores at the start of the list, and the tie breakers need to be in non-reversed alphabetical order. the output should be this:
    ['Claudia Zingaro,50', 'Ivan Connolly,50', 'Jeffie Honaker,50', 'Floria Rozar,49', 'Hyun Castleberry,48', 'Invalid Name,48', 'Cristi Authement,47', 'Yadira Millwood,47', 'Invalid Name,46']

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort(key=...)` function.

Try this:

```
L = ['Ivan Connolly,50', 'Claudia Zingaro,50', 'Jeffie Honaker,50', 'Floria Rozar,49', 'Hyun Castleberry,48', 'Invalid Name,48', 'Cristi Authement,47', 'Yadira Millwood,47', 'Invalid Name,46']
L.sort(key=lambda x:int(x.split(',')[1]))
```

Output:

```
['Invalid Name,46', 'Cristi Authement,47', 'Yadira Millwood,47', 'Hyun Castleberry,48', 'Invalid Name,48', 'Floria Rozar,49', 'Ivan Connolly,50', 'Claudia Zingaro,50', 'Jeffie Honaker,50']
```

It is simple and clear.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with:

```
L = ['Ivan Connolly,50', 'Claudia Zingaro,50', 'Jeffie Honaker,50', 'Floria Rozar,49', 'Hyun Castleberry,48', 'Invalid Name,48', 'Cristi Authement,47', 'Yadira Millwood,47', 'Invalid Name,46']
```

To sort by multiple keys, first, sort on the "secondary" key in the order you wish it to be, eg, we'll put it in alphabetical order ignoring case:

```
L.sort(key=str.lower)
```

Gives us:

```
['Claudia Zingaro,50', 'Cristi Authement,47', 'Floria Rozar,49', 'Hyun Castleberry,48', 'Invalid Name,46', 'Invalid Name,48', 'Ivan Connolly,50', 'Jeffie Honaker,50', 'Yadira Millwood,47']
```

Then, we sort in descending order the score field:

```
L.sort(key=lambda L: int(L.rpartition(',')[2]), reverse=True)
```

That gives `L` a final result of:

```
['Claudia Zingaro,50', 'Ivan Connolly,50', 'Jeffie Honaker,50', 'Floria Rozar,49', 'Hyun Castleberry,48', 'Invalid Name,48', 'Cristi Authement,47', 'Yadira Millwood,47', 'Invalid Name,46']
```